# How to give the user the ability to add another choice data?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have a select dropdown menu, The user selects one of the options then the related form inputs are shown.

Here is the html:

```
<select id="relative" name="relative">
    <option>Select relative</option>
    <option value="father">father</option>
    <option value="mother">mother</option>
    <option value="brother">brother</option>
</select>

<div id="relative_sections">
    <div id="father">
        <input type="text" id="father_name" name="father_name" placeholder="Name" />
        <input type="email" id="father_email" name="father_email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="number" id="father_phone" name="father_phone" placeholder="phone" />
    </div>
    <div id="mother">
        <input type="text" id="mother_name" name="mother_name" placeholder="Name" />
        <input type="email" id="mother_email" name="mother_email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="number" id="mother_phone" name="mother_phone" placeholder="phone" />
    </div>
    <div id="brother">
        <input type="text" id="brother_name" name="brother_name" placeholder="Name" />
        <input type="email" id="brother_email" name="brother_email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="number" id="brother_phone" name="brother_phone" placeholder="phone" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code for hiding all the sections:

```
#mother, 
#father, 
#brother{
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript code to show/hide sections on changing selected option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideAllChildrenButOne(parentId, toRevealId) {
         var children = document.getElementById(parentId).children;
         for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++) children[i].style.display="none";
         document.getElementById(toRevealId).style.display="block";
    }

    document.getElementById('relative').addEventListener('change', function(){
        if (this.value !== '') {
            hideAllChildrenButOne('relative_sections', this.value);
        }else{
            var children = document.getElementById('relative_sections').children;
            for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++) children[i].style.display="none";
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is a live fiddle to see what is going on: http://jsfiddle.net/38db59cx

Then I validate the inputs depending on the selected value:

```
if($_POST['relative'] == 'father'){
    //Validate the inputs
}elseif($_POST['relative'] == 'mother'){
    //Validate the inputs
}elseif($_POST['relative'] == 'brother'){
    //Validate the inputs
}
```

What I want do is to give the user the ability to select more than one option like ('father' and 'mother') or even all of them then I validate all, But he must at least fill one option data.

How to do this so the user at least select one option, fills the inputs for this option and still could select another option, So that I can validate  what he selects?

Most important thing is that the user should select at least one and fill the related ata and can also select more than one.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your select box to either a multiple select or checkboxes. If using checkboxes you would set the name to `name='relative[]`.

Checkboxes:

```
<label>father<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="father"></label>
<label>mother<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="mother"></label>
<label>brother<input type="checkbox" name="relative[]" value="brother"></label>
```

MultiSelect

`<select name="relative" multiple>`

Then in php you can read the data like this:

```
// create a container to hold the validated results
$aRelative = array();

// if post data exists proceed to check the resutls
if(isset($_POST['relative'])){
    // loop over each post value
    foreach($_POST['relative'] as $iPos => $a){
        // do some validation on the result 
        if($a != ""){
            $aRelative[] &= $a;
        }
    }
}
if(!empty($aRelative)){
    //do whatever with the data
}
```

Comment: `issest()` should be `isset()`. And `id(...)` should be `if(...)` here. Can you fix those please?

Comment: Thanks @FunkFortyNiner were you the downvoter? I can't see whats wrong with this approach

Comment: Had nothing to do with the approach, it was the errors you made.

Answer (score -1):

So to my understanding, you want user to select multiple option and want to validate them as well. So here is the piece of code which I am sharing. You need to use attribute 'multiple' in your select tag for multiple options to get selected. Here it is:
[Click here and check the code, you want to do something similar](http://jsfiddle.net/aDxu8/1/)

In the javascript, you can do something this and add validation for the options.

```
$('#RNA').submit(function(){
     var options = $('#sampleMut > option:selected');
     if(options.length == 0){
         alert('no value selected');
         return false;
     }
});
```

Note: To select more than one option you need to do => press command/CTRL + click options.
Hope it helps a little!

Comment: It doesn't have to be `<select>`, I want to let the user know the he must fill one at least and fill more if he wants

Comment: I need something simple that the user can understand what he should do

Comment: This is the one which is commonly used by people. You can add a custom message also to select at least one field.

Comment: What about mobile users, How could they select more than 1 option?